# Error when printing string and float

Tags: python, printing, format

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fptr = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    for line in fptr:
        list1 = []
        s = ''
        for item in re.findall(r'[\S]+', line):
            try:
                list1.append(int(item))
            except:
                s = s + item + ' '
        if not len(list1) == 0:
            avg = sum(list1) / len(list1)
            print(list1)
            print(s)
            print(avg)
            print("{0:.3f} {}".format(avg, s)) //ERROR OCCUR
```

This the stdout:

```
[12, 14, 5, 20]
From sample set A
12.75
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parse.py", line 28, in <module>
    print("{0:.3f} {}".format(avg, s))
ValueError: cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering
```

It seems the string and the average value can be printed individually. But why can't I print them together?

Comment: Because your field numbering isn't consistent, as the error message tells you; use `"{0:.3f} {1}"` or `"{:.3f} {}"`, but **be consistent**.

Answer (score 17):

Python is complaining that you numbered the first format field but not the second.  Either number them both:

```
print("{0:.3f} {1}".format(avg, s))
#       ^       ^
```

or don't number them at all:

```
print("{:.3f} {}".format(avg, s))
```

Note however that the second solution only works in Python 2.6 or greater.

Comment: Ah.. I didn't notice that. It's now working. Thank you!